# configure error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, linker, gcc4.7

I was trying to install rvm ( \curl -L https://get.rvm.io |    bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles). It worked fine until ZI got a configure error:

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/home/nishant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /home/nishant/.rvm/log/1379591052_ruby-2.0.0-p247/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Following are the contents of the mentioned log file:

```
[2013-09-19 17:15:58] ./configure
current path: /home/nishant/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247
command(4): ./configure --prefix=/home/nishant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/nishant/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I then tried a "hello world" C program and got the following error on compilation:

```
nishant@nishant-Inspiron-1545:~$ gcc -g -o hello hello.c 
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure why this error is thrown. I couldn't find a satisfactory answer to this on the forum. Could someone please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that I solved buy installing certs and libs for building C programs

```
apt-get install build-essential
```